Why does dumping heap with --heapsnapshot-signal=signal flag instantly revert memory usage to baseline?
I encountered a weird scenario. I run a nodejs application that uses around 70MB of Heap memory. It occasionally spikes to ~1.7GB, so I tried to find the case by taking snapshot with --heapsnapshot-signal=signal flag because my application setup that includes Docker, load balancer, pm2 etc. makes the other methods very inconvenient.
The weird behavior is that after I sent signal to the spiked process, the memory usage as observed by top and pm2 INSTANTLY drop from 1.7 GB to its 70 MB baseline and then the resulting heap size was only 70MB.
What could possibly be the cause? How else could I possibly do the profiling if the heap dumping is impossible?
I tried increasing max-old-space-size, using trace-gc. I expected that increasing memory limit should stop the snap-back-to-baseline behavior and let me get the should-be-correct large heap

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
